# WiFi 802.11 Deauthentication not handled by iOS 5.1.1, iPhone 3GS

Tags: ios, objective-c, wifi

I am working on an iOS App that communicates to an UDP socket on a WiFi Devices which creates an (Soft-)Accesspoint.

The WiFi device drops all connected devices by sending 802.11 Deauthentication messages after a period of inactivity (like 60s). Obviously the iPhone 3GS running iOS 5.1.1 does not react to this Deauthentication correctly and "thinks" it is still connected to the WiFi network. UDP commands from the iPhone which are send after disconnection are replied with 802.11 Deauthentication messages from the device. No Association request is sent (probably due to the  iPhone is thinking to be still connected to the Accesspoint. (-> Wireshark sniff)

Other devices / other iOS Versions do send a Association request and behave correctly.

Any idea how to solve this issue or how to check, if the iPhone 3GS is *really* connected to the WiFi Network?

BTW: I am using the CocoaAsyncSocket for communication, but probably this is irrelevant.

Comment: What do you mean by *really* connected? According to your description it is connected